# how to reuse cabal compiled modules when using ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a fairly large haskell project, and running ghci on some files can require compiling dozens or hundreds of modules before it gets to a prompt, which can take a number of minutes. I'm using cabal, and so I generally have already compiled object files under dist/. But ghci only looks for .o files next to the source .hs files; it does not know about cabal's dist/. Is there any simple and good way to make ghci load those object files rather than recompiling everything on its own?

I'm asking for a simple and good way, because I have complicated and ugly ways to do it. :)
For example, this will make ghci reuse the cabal compiled modules. I came up with this command
line by copying, and modifying the way cabal runs ghc, ensuring that it sets everything the same as the last cabal build, which is necessary to make sure ghci will load the modules.

ghci -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace -i -idist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -odir dist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp -hidir dist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp -stubdir dist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp -XHaskell98 dist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp/Utility/libdiskfree.o dist/build/git-annex/git-annex-tmp/Utility/libmounts.o

Seems to me it should be possible for a "cabal ghci" to calculate this command line and run it, or perhaps there is a tool I don't know of that already does so.

Comment: Have you actually made cabal _register_ the compiled modules (`cabal install`)?

Comment: No, because they are part of a application, and are being changed as I develop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the odir and ohi options to point to the cabal build directory like so: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#output-files

Comment: Just -odir by itself does not seem to be enough for ghci to be happy with the cabal objects. -ohi seems to be for a single interface file and unnecessary. My command line above does include -odir, and most of the other stuff in it also seems necessary to make ghci happy.